# Trouble printing reversed linked list (java)

Tags: java

Basically, I have created methods that print a linked list of integers, delete duplicates from the linked list, as well as invert the linked list. Everything works fine...almost.For some reason, I cannot get my printLinked() method to work after the list has been inverted. For the time being, I just created a while loop to output the reversed list so that I can at least be sure that the list is being reversed. I need to have the printLinked() method do this, though. If anyone can help me out or point me in the right direction in terms of figuring out what the problem is, then I would appreciate it much.
Thank you.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class ListTest
 {

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    ListNode head = new ListNode();
    ListNode tail = head;
    tail.link = null;

    int input;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter integers into list; end by entering a zero");
    input = keyboard.nextInt();

    ListNode temp;

    while (input != 0)
    {

        temp = new ListNode();
        temp.data = input;
        temp.link = null;
        tail.link = temp;
        tail = temp;

        input = keyboard.nextInt();


    }

    System.out.println("You entered the following integers : ");
    printLinked(head.link);

    delrep(head);
    System.out.println("After deleting repeating integers, you are left with : ");
    printLinked(head.link);


    System.out.println("Your inverted list of integers is now : ");
    invert(head);

    printLinked(head.link);








}


    public static void printLinked(ListNode list)
    {
        ListNode cursor = list;

        while (cursor != null)
        {

            System.out.print(cursor.data + " ");
            cursor = cursor.link;
        }



        System.out.println("");


    }


        public static void delrep(ListNode head)
        {

            ListNode temp = new ListNode();




            while(head != null)
            {
                temp = head;

                while(temp.link != null)
                 {
                    if(head.data == temp.link.data)
                    {
                        ListNode temp2 = new ListNode();
                        temp2 = temp.link;
                        temp.link = temp2.link;
                        temp2 = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         temp = temp.link;
                    }
                  }

                   head = head.link;
                }

            }


public static void invert(ListNode head)
        {

            ListNode temp1 = null;
            ListNode temp2 = null;


            while (head != null)
            {
                temp1 = head.link;
                head.link = temp2;
                temp2 = head;
                head = temp1;



            }

            head = temp2;





                         //This portion of code needs to be removed. I added this part just so I can visually
                         //confirm that the list is reversing until I can get the print method to work for the
                         // reversed list.

            while (head.link != null)
            {
                System.out.print(head.data + " ");
                head = head.link;
            }
            System.out.println("");


    }
```

}

also, this is what my ListNode class is:

```
    public class ListNode
```

{

```
public int data;
public ListNode link;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the new head of the list at your invert method:

```
public static ListNode invert(ListNode head) {
    ListNode temp1;
    ListNode temp2 = null;

    while (head != null) {
        temp1 = head.link;
        head.link = temp2;
        temp2 = head;
        head = temp1;
    }

    return temp2;
}
```

And use the returned value when printing:

```
System.out.println("Your inverted list of integers is now : ");
ListNode result = invert(head);

printLinked(result.link);
```

It wasn't printing because you were using the original head that was now the tail of the list.